# Update Phone to Tablet Layout PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

Hi we have completed an application Phone Layout and there is a request to have Desktop/Tablet layout for it.

Should we creating a new copy and convert it manually to Tablet/Desktop or check and adjust it to Responsive Layout.

Comment: You want to target it both for phone and tablet or just tablet going forward?

Comment: Both tablet and phone

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, you have both the options for creating a Desktop/Tablet supported application:

1. Create a new application with Tablet layout
2. Make same application responsive which will work for both phone and desktop/tablet.

It is up to you how you want to go ahead. But before that, you should consider below points:

1. If you create a new application with Tablet layout:

   i) It will be easier to develop and comparatively will take less time to replicate existing phone layout app to tablet layout app

   ii) If you make any changes to existing functionality or add new enhancements in one application - you will have to replicate same logic in another type of application. So, there might be version mismatching if you keep using both the applications.

   **Reference**: [Mobile Layout AND Tablet Layout for PowerApp](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Mobile-Layout-AND-Tablet-Layout-for-PowerApp/td-p/347886)
2. If you create a responsive application:

   i) Comparatively, it will take more time to make existing application responsive while will work for all screen sizes.

   ii) You will need to learn (if new to it) and implement responsiveness in your application as canvas application does not support this automatically.

   iii) There will be no problem of versioning mismatching if you use single application for all screen sizes

   **References**:

   1. [Create responsive layouts in canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/create-responsive-layout)
   2. [Building responsive canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/build-responsive-apps)

If users are ready to use different applications for different screen sizes (phone and desktop/tablet),  you want tablet application ready quickly and likely there will be less changes in application functionality going forward - *create a new application with Tablet layout*.

Comment: Thanks! will proceed creating new application with Tablet Layout.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you!